# Remove words from a list which have recurring characters in Python3

Tags: python, list

When I run this code:

```
li=["It","is","funny","how","I","fiddled","with","this"]
for i in range(0,len(li)):
    word=li[i]
    for j in range(0,len(word)-1):
        if word[j] == word[j+1]:
            li.pop(i)
            break
print(li)
```

My desired output is:

```
['It','is','how','I','with','this']
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "fiddle.py", line 3, in <module>
word=li[i]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Please point out the mistake in my code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove items from a list while iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Comment: `i` changes from 0 to 7 during the loop.  By the time `i` reaches 6, you have removed two items from the list so it only has six items in it and its *largest* index is 5 -    that is why  `li[6]` gives you an index error.  printing variables at different places in a loop is a good simple troubleshooting tool that will show you what is happening while the code is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
new_list = [x for x in li if len(x) == len(set(x))]
```

Also, you should never iterate a list and remove elements while at it. The best approach is to create a new one

If you want to remove 2 identical chars together:

```
new_list = [x for x in li if not re.search(r'([a-zA-Z])\1', x)]
```

Comment: That'll only keep words with unique characters - I believe the OP is actually trying to only remove words that contain consecutive duplicate characters.

Comment: @JBernardo You are right. I shouldn't have iterated the list and removed the elements at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use a regular expression to identify duplicate runs of the same character in a string and put that in a list-comp, eg:

```
import re

li=["It","is","funny","how","I","fiddled","with","this"]
wanted = [el for el in li if not re.search(r'(.)\1', el)]
```

Gives you:

```
['It', 'is', 'how', 'I', 'with', 'this']
```

Answer (score 0):

At this point:

```
for i in range(0,len(li)):
```

`len(li)` equals 8, so your loop goes from 0 to 7. However, since you're removing items from `li` inside the loop, `li` becomes shorter than 8 elements before `i` reaches 7. Then you get the error.